# find paths through a maze

Tags: maze

I want find distinct possible path in maze from start to end point
I have written code but it gives me only some path in maze... i want all paths
Please give some suggestions

Comment: Recursion is your friend.

Comment: I cannot understand your grid representation.  If 0 represents allowed, 1 represents blocked, and you have a 4x4 grid, don't you need more than four lists to describe possible edges?

Comment: @InbarRose: His function is already recursive, so that's not very helpful.

Comment: Why did you remove all your code ? answers in python with modified code seems weird now.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using generators:

```
grid = [[0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0]]

def search(sr, sc, er, ec, path):

    if sr < 0 or sc < 0 or sr >= len(grid) or sc >= len(grid[0]):
        return
    if (sr, sc) in path or grid[sr][sc] == 1:
        return

    path.append((sr, sc))
    if (sr, sc) == (er, ec):
        yield path
    else:
        for possible_path in search(sr+1, sc, er, ec, list(path)):
            yield possible_path
        for possible_path in search(sr-1, sc, er, ec, list(path)):
            yield possible_path
        for possible_path in search(sr, sc+1, er, ec, list(path)):
            yield possible_path
        for possible_path in search(sr, sc-1, er, ec, list(path)):
            yield possible_path
```

If you want to go from (0,1) to (3,3):

```
print list(search(0, 1, 3, 3, []))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
[(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
[(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Recursive generator, like it!

Answer (score 0):

Insert a

```
grid[sx][sy] = 0
```

when you remove the `[sx, sy]` from path again (i. e. right before the `return`) in order to mark that cell as not visited again.

Also, you might want to change the line

```
solution.append(path)
```

to

```
solution.append(path[:])
```

to create a copy of that solution in order to keep it for later.  Without the `[:]` you just add another reference to the same list which gets changed in the process later so that you will end up with a list of empty lists in `solution`.

*AND* you should think about not using global variables.  I think to `yield` each found solution from a generator would be much nicer than appending it to a global variable.  But that's a different aspect and a little out of scope here.